# Convertig an int item from list for mysql command[python , mysql ]

Tags: python, mysql, apache, list

I am writing a script for an MySql-Server and i need an int-variable from a list of integers for an mysql command.

The list ID looks like that `(2028,) (1029,) (4000,)`

If i use for example `ID[1]` and put this into the command i get an error , because the Server needs a pure int variable  and not an item from a list.

The output looks like that :

```
print(ID[1])   (2028,)
```

But i need the variable like this :

```
print(ID[1])  2028
```

Is there any converting command for this?

Comment: `ID[1][0]`? You can index tuples, too.

Comment: thank you it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try print (ID[1][0]). List is of tuples which contains int.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked very well . Thank you for the fast answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your list of tuples into list of integers.

For example if you have

```
data = [(2028,), (1029,), (4000,)]
```

you can do

```
>>> print [entry[0] for entry in data]
[2028, 1029, 4000]
```